# Best way to matchup & merge 2 seperate dataframes in python by column/row values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, compare

I have 2 dataframes outputted from my python script: `dt1` & `dt2`

Each dataframe has 4 columns (`colA`, `colB`, `colC`, & `colD`) and each dataframe has a different length (`dt1` always has more rows)

I want to create a 3rd dataframe `dt3` that:

1. copies `dt1`
2. adds `dt2[colD]` value to the corresponding row IF `dt1[colA]` = `dt2[colA]` & `dt1[colB]` = `dt2[colB]` & `dt1[colC]` = `dt2[colC]`, if the 3 columns don't match I want to load null

I've tried iterating through using a for loop with combined if else statements but can't seem to get the check piece right, please help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking for help always create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This means providing a sample of the DataFrames and the expected output inside a code block along with your code attempt, so we can easily reproduce the problem. Only describing in words your data and the problem you are having often leads to misunderstandings. A good way is to share the outputs of `print(df.to_dict())` along with `print(df)`, where `df` are your DataFrames. This allows us to clearly understand what you want and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `merge` from `pandas`

```
df1.merge(df2[["colA","colB","colC","colD"]],on=["colA","colB","colC"])
```

Updated as Op req.

```
df1.colD.fillna('---')
```

Comment: This is a good start! But it only loads the rows/elements that are equal. How do I fill out the rest of the new table with the rest of dt1 & null for dt2?

Comment: df1.merge(df2[["colA","colB","colC","colD"]],on=["colA","colB","colC"],how='left')

Comment: Thank you, this works great! Is there a way to replace "NaN" with "---"? Thank you so much

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Thank you! Needed to set inplace = True. If I wanted to add a 3rd dataframe to the merge do I just mimic what we did for df2 after another comma?